# Datastructures for storing sorted values

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, key-value, sortedmap

My data is in the form of key value.i want to sort values.i have stored them in hashmap.

`map.put(1,.8678)

map.put(2,.9578) 
map.put(6,.0453)`

i want output:

```
(6,.0453), (1,.8678), (2,.9578)
```

I want to sort values, retrive sorted values and their keys efficient(with the least complexity).What is the best data structure for my problem?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java || this was answered before, it may help you.

Comment: You could create a `Pair` class that wraps the two values then sort with a custom comparator. You can store the pairs in a set using an appropriate hashcode/equals.

Comment: @MuhammedRamadanAdly none of the answeres has tick beside it.

Answer (score -1):

use a TreeMap instead of a hashmap

Comment: I didn't down vote but TreeMap would sort based on keys. OP wants to sort by values.